# Algorithms to solve for an arbitrary multivariate equation?

Tags: algorithms, nonlinear-optimization

I am wondering what the algorithm or approach is to find the unique solution for a single arbitrary multivariable equation? For example what approach does wolfram alpha or matlab use when I enter in an equation with unique solutions (composed of non-elementary functions) for them to solve?

Also can someone tell me the official name of this type of problem as I couldn't find anything online when I googled "equation solver algorithm"

It seems like this problem can be cast into a nonlinear programming problem, but I'm not sure if these techniques are what's used.

Comment: There isn't even an algorithm for solving one-variable equations, much less for multivariable equations. The approach depends very much on exactly which equation it is that you are trying to solve – it's a package, not an approach.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So if I enter in a random equation into wolfram alpha, how does it figure out what approach to use?

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to get your hands on the documentation for its code to see how it does it. Then again, if I hand you a random integral to evaluate, how do you decide between substitution, parts, partial fractions, contour integration, trapezoid rule, Simpson's rule, ...?